# Ionos Dedicated Ubuntu Pleask Server Not Reachable, Dropping Network?

Tags: suspend, netplan

SITUATION:
I have four Ionos Dedicated Ubuntu Pleask Servers all setup with 1 week.
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS / Plesk Obsidian 18.0.41
Two of the servers are reliable.
Two of the servers become unreachable about every 5 - 7 days and they stop serving sites & email.
This happens unpredictable days and times, and not at the same time.
A login the Ionos Control panal and reboot gets them back online.
When it is not functioning, it appears to ban individuals that continue to try to get email. I then need to release their IP.

BACKGROUND RESEARCH:

1. Ionos support suggests this is an issue with Ubuntu 20.4 related to Sleep-and-Hibernation, to solve, disable them.
   see https://linux-tips.us/how-to-disable-sleep-and-hibernation-on-ubuntu-server/
2. Plesk community help points to 50-cloud-init.yaml needing a line: critical:true, so it will designate the connection as “critical to the system”, meaning that special care will be taken to not release the assigned IP when the daemon is restarted. See https://talk.plesk.com/threads/network-drops-every-12-hours.361876/page-2#post-905535

QUESTIONS:
Are the above on track?, which is the best way to go? OR is this an issue with Ionos hardware? Will this be fixed with a Ubuntu patch? Why would it be only Two servers is a big question to me! Thanks for any input.

Comment: I see no reason to think that either of those suggestions are on the right track.  `critical` only matters when something else resets the network management service; nothing in a standard Ubuntu system is going to do this, every 5-7 days or otherwise.  Furthermore, an interface NOT being marked critical means only that the interface may *temporarily* become unavailable during a daemon restart.  And suspend/hibernate is also an unlikely explanation, the default Ubuntu configuration works without issue on a large range of clouds and physical servers.

Comment: If your cloud provider is generating ACPI power events that are causing Ubuntu to suspend, the question should be: why is the cloud provider doing that?!

Comment: To further debug what is actually happening, I suggest you start with `journalctl -b -1` after your reboot.  This will show what was being logged to systemd before the reboot.  This should help you narrow down the problem: it may not be a problem with the network stack at all, perhaps the kernel is crashing.  The logs should help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your knowledge  slangasek! I am expecting it to happen soon, even thought it would have happened yesterday. I will report back. Thanks again! Sincerely, Brad

Comment: Hi, it did go down this morning.  This is what it showed   # journalctl -b -1  -p "emerg".."crit"
-- Logs begin at Thu 2022-03-10 13:10:47 EST, end at Wed 2022-03-30 00:12:09 EDT. --
Mar 21 18:51:33 z......com dovecot[758096]: imap-login: Panic: file client-common.c: line 1182 (client_common_deinit): assertion failed: (destroyed_clients == NU>
Mar 23 20:18:57 z......com dovecot[758685]: imap-login: Fatal: Dovecot version mismatch: Master is v2.3.17.1, imap-login is v2.3.18 (if you don't care, set versi>

Comment: Mar 23 20:18:59 z......com dovecot[758685]: imap-login: Fatal: Dovecot version mismatch: Master is v2.3.17.1, imap-login is v2.3.18 (if you don't care, set versi>
Mar 23 20:19:03 z......com dovecot[758685]: imap-login: Fatal: Dovecot version mismatch: Master is v2.3.17.1, imap-login is v2.3.18 (if you don't care, set versi>
Mar 23 20:19:11 z......com dovecot[758685]: imap-login: Fatal: Dovecot version mismatch: Master is v2.3.17.1, imap-login is v2.3.18 (if you don't care, set versi>

Comment: Mar 23 20:19:17 z......com dovecot[758685]: pop3-login: Fatal: Dovecot version mismatch: Master is v2.3.17.1, pop3-login is v2.3.18 (if you don't care, set versi>
Mar 29 05:21:12 z......com sshd[1895942]: fatal: userauth_finish: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
Mar 29 05:21:13 z......com sshd[1895944]: fatal: userauth_finish: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
Mar 29 05:21:13 z.....com sshd[1895947]: fatal: userauth_finish: Connection reset by peer [preauth] ... now to figure this out, (I removed the server name) thanks for any help :)

Comment: I would suggest looking at the very last log entries in the journal regardless of severity.  The dovecot messages look like something you would want to take care of, but would not have anything to do with the system losing connectivity.

Comment: Thanks! I need to run it on the next time it goes down. Not sure of the day now. I also need to learn how to move to a set date, so many lines in the output!

Comment: I located the lines before the reboot. I do not know what to look for, but I am not see anything that looks like it would cause the drop. Mainly email stuff going on.

Comment: I am learning how to use journalctl, Thanks so much :)

Comment: It just stop working. It shows a connect from unknown[41.139.37.131] at 8:25 ...then no log until reboot at 9:45   -- Before this entry, it seem to show normal activity.  I also run the journalctl -b -1  -p "emerg".."crit" which showed no records. I did a traceroute, on hop 11 it showed west-indian-ocean-cable-company-ltd.10gigabitethernet5-3.core1.lon3.he.net then resolved in 6 more hops.  Any thoughts? Thanks, Brad

Comment: I think that last unknown[41.139.37.131] connection is not the key. It does not show the other time it went down. Last time it was an normal email connection.

Comment: If this is a hardware failure situation, what would be the best test/analysis to run?